# How to solve ORA-00936: missing expression?

Tags: java, android, jsp

I am new here :) Help me what is missing? I want to view and update each data from database instead got error massage => java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00936: missing expression <= Thank you!

i hope you guys can help me, iam getting trouble to post this question also :')

this is usercontroller

```js
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import assignment3.connection.ConnectionManager;
import assignment3.model.User;

public class UserDAO {
    
    static Connection currentCon = null;
    static ResultSet rs = null; 
    static PreparedStatement ps=null;
    static Statement stmt=null;
    static String firstname, lastname, username, password;

    public User getUser(User user) {
        firstname = user.getFirstname();

        String searchQuery = "select * from myuser where firstname='" + firstname + "'";

        try {
            currentCon = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
            stmt = currentCon.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(searchQuery);
            boolean more = rs.next();
            
            System.out.println(searchQuery);

            // if user exists set the isValid variable to true
            if (more) {
                user.setValid(true);
            }
           
            else if (!more) {               
                user.setValid(false);
            }
           
        }

        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Register failed: An Exception has occurred! " + ex);
        }

        finally {
            if (rs != null) {
                try {
                    rs.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                rs = null;
            }
            
            if (stmt != null) {
                try {
                    stmt.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                stmt = null;
            }

            if (currentCon != null) {
                try {
                    currentCon.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

                currentCon = null;
            }
        }
        
        return user;
    }
    
    public void add(User user) {
        
        firstname = user.getFirstname();
        lastname = user.getLastname();
        username = user.getUsername();
        password = user.getPassword();
        
       
        try {
            currentCon = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
            ps=currentCon.prepareStatement("insert into myuser (firstname, lastname, username, password)values(?,?,?,?)");
            ps.setString(1,firstname);
            ps.setString(2,lastname);
            ps.setString(3,username);
            ps.setString(4,password);
            ps.executeUpdate();
        
            System.out.println("Firstname is " + firstname);
            System.out.println("Lastname is " + lastname);
            System.out.println("Username is " + username);
            System.out.println("Password is " + password);
            
        }

        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("failed: An Exception has occurred! " + ex);
        }

        finally {
            if (ps != null) {
                try {
                    ps.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                ps = null;
            }
            
            if (currentCon != null) {
                try {
                    currentCon.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                currentCon = null;
            }
        }
        

    }
    public List<User> getAllUser() {
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
          
          try {
            currentCon = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
            stmt = currentCon.createStatement();
          
              String q = "select * from myuser";
              ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(q);
              
              while (rs.next()) {
                  User user = new User();                 
                  
                  user.setFirstname(rs.getString("firstname"));
                  user.setLastname(rs.getString("lastname"));
                  user.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));
                  user.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
                  users.add(user);
              }
          } catch (SQLException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

          return users;
    }
    
    public void deleteUser(String firstname) {
        String searchQuery = "delete from myuser where firstname='" + firstname + "'";
        
        System.out.println(searchQuery);
        
        try {
            
            currentCon = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
            stmt = currentCon.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate(searchQuery);
        
        } catch (SQLException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          } 
    }

    public User getUserByFirstname(String firstname) {
    
        User user = new User();
        
        try {
            currentCon = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
            ps = currentCon.prepareStatement("select from myuser where firstname = ?");
            
            ps.setString(1, firstname);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            
            if (rs.next()) {
                  user.setFirstname(rs.getString("firstname"));
                  user.setLastname(rs.getString("lastname"));
                  user.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));
                  user.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
            }
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          
        }
        
        return user;
    }
    
    public void updateUser(User user) {
        
        firstname = user.getFirstname();
        lastname = user.getLastname();
        username = user.getUsername();
        password = user.getPassword();
        
        String searchQuery = "UPDATE myuser SET lastname='" + lastname + "' , username= '" + username + "' , password= '" + password + "' WHERE firstname ='" + firstname +"'";
        
        try {
                    
            currentCon = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
            stmt = currentCon.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate(searchQuery);
                   
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    
    }
    
}
```

This is userDAO
I want to view and update data from very data from database.

```js
import java.io.IOException;

import jakarta.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import assignment3.dao.UserDAO;
import assignment3.model.User;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class SubjectController
 */
@WebServlet("/UserController")
public class UserController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private static String MAIN_PAGE = "index.jsp";
    private static String LIST_USER = "viewUserList.jsp";
    private static String VIEW_USER = "viewUser.jsp";
    private static String UPDATE_USER = "updateUser.jsp";
    
    private UserDAO daoUser;
    
    String forward="";
       
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public UserController() {
        super();
        daoUser = new UserDAO();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String action = request.getParameter("action");
        
        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("listUser")) {
            
            forward = LIST_USER;
            request.setAttribute("users", daoUser.getAllUser());
                    
        } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("deleteUser")) {
            
            String firstname = request.getParameter("firstname");
            
            daoUser.deleteUser(firstname);
            
            forward = LIST_USER;
            request.setAttribute("users", daoUser.getAllUser());
        
        } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("viewUser")) {
        
            String firstname = request.getParameter("firstname");
            
            User user = new User();
            user = daoUser.getUserByFirstname(firstname);
            
            forward = VIEW_USER;
            request.setAttribute("user", user);
            
        } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("updateUser")) {
            
            String firstname = request.getParameter("firstname");
            
            User user = new User();
            user = daoUser.getUserByFirstname(firstname);
            
            forward = UPDATE_USER;
            request.setAttribute("user", user);
        
        } else {
            forward = MAIN_PAGE;
        }
        
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(forward);
        view.forward(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String firstname = request.getParameter("firstname");
        String lastname = request.getParameter("lastname");
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        
        User user = new User(firstname, lastname, username, password);              
        
        user = daoUser.getUser(user);
    
        if(!user.isValid()){            
            System.out.println("inserting user");
            daoUser.add(user);          
            response.sendRedirect("register.jsp");
        
        } else {
            
            System.out.println("User Already Exist");
            daoUser.updateUser(user);

            RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(VIEW_USER);
            request.setAttribute("user", daoUser.getUserByFirstname(firstname));
            view.forward(request, response);
        }
    }

    
    
}
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Which SQL statement produces this exception?

Comment: You may want to use prepared statements in order to prevent sql exceptions.

Comment: view and update

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is with the SQL query and please check the full stack trace for the exception, it will be pointing to the specific position which is incorrect or you can try the query causing issue directly on the SQL client to know the exact issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but can you explain more how can I check that?

Answer (score 0):

The select statement in the getUserByFirstname method is missing the *.

The original code in your question:

```
public User getUserByFirstname(String firstname) {

    User user = new User();
    
    try {
        currentCon = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
        ps = currentCon.prepareStatement("select from myuser where firstname = ?");
        
        ps.setString(1, firstname);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

The correct select statement:

```
        ps = currentCon.prepareStatement("select * from myuser where firstname = ?");
```